# Replace string in file with dictionary values

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a file (usearch.txt) with entries that look like this:

0 AM158981
0 AM158980
0 AM158982
etc.

I want to replace the accession numbers in this file (AM158981, etc.) with the bacterial names that correspond to it, which are in a second file (acs.txt):

AM158981 Brucella   pinnipedialis   Brucellaceae
AM158980 Brucella   suis    Brucellaceae
AM158982 Brucella   ceti    Brucellaceae
etc.

My plan was to make a dictionary using the second file (accession number as the key, names as the value), and then open the first file and use the dictionary to replace the accession numbers and save this to a new file (done.txt):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import re
# Creates a dictionary for accession numbers

fname = r"acs.txt"

namer = {}
for line in open(fname):
        acs, name = line.split(" ",1)
        namer[acs] = str(name)

infilename = "usearch.txt"
outfilename = "done.txt"

regex = re.compile(r'\d+\s(\w+)')

with open(infilename, 'r') as infile, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        x = regex.sub(r'\1', namer(name), line)

        outfile.write(x)
```

I get this error when I run this script: Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "nameit.py", line 21, in <module>
  x = regex.sub(r'\1', namer(name), line)
  TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Ideally, my "done.txt" file would look like this:

0 Brucella  pinnipedialis   Brucellaceae
0 Brucella  suis    Brucellaceae
0 Brucella  ceti    Brucellaceae

Comment: dict access is namer[name]

Comment: I changed it to namer[name] and got this: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `namer` like a method:

```
x = regex.sub(r'\1', namer(name), line)
```

You want to replace the parentheses with brackets to access the element with the key `name`:

```
x = regex.sub(r'\1', namer[name], line)
```

Note you'll also need to get the name again or you'll use the same key over and over:

```
with open(infilename, 'r') as infile, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        # Need to get the ID for the bacteria in question. If we don't, everything
        # will end up with the same name in our output file.
        _, name = line.split(" ", 1)

        # Strip the newline character
        name = name.strip()

        x = regex.sub(r'\1', namer[name], line)
        outfile.write(x)
```

Comment: I changed it to namer[name] and got this: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable.

Comment: @Jen What's the full error? It should give you the line it doesn't like.

Comment: @Jen Also, what happens if you print `name` right before the `regex.sub`?

Comment: the full error is: File "nameit.py", line 21, in <module>
    x = regex.sub(r'\1', namer(name), line)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable. I will try the 'print name' bit right now...

Comment: i know the error has namer(name) but my script has the square brackets

Comment: Are you sure you're modifying the right file? Did you install it and use a copy?

Comment: @ThomasFenzl I'm sure I'm modifying the right file, I'm not using a copy

Comment: @thegrinner I added print name right about the x = regex.sub line  and got this: kakaw:LTPs111 jenny$ python nameit.py 
Zymophilus raffinosivorans Veillonellaceae
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nameit.py", line 22, in <module>
    x = regex.sub(r'\1', namer[name], line)
KeyError: 'Zymophilus\traffinosivorans\tVeillonellaceae'  (the file i am working with has many names, that's why the Zymophilus name isn't actually in the question I posted)

Comment: @Jen Hmm, so it looks like the bracket changed took. It also looks like you'll need to add `acs, name = line.split(" ",1)` back in where you put that print statement so your keys match. Right now `name` is never going to change.

Comment: @thegrinner What do you mean by 'add acs, name = line.split(" ", 1) to the print statement? (I'm new to programming so I'm an idiot) :P

Comment: Might be worth putting in `namer.get(name, name)` if it's appropriate for something without a full name to retain its code value

Comment: @Jen Right now, you only set `name` to a value when you loop through your dictionary file. When you start looping through input file to write to the output file, `name` is never changed. So if `name` was something like `foo`, everything in the output file would use the `foo` value in your name dictionary. I edited my answer to show how you can get the name - see if it makes sense.

Comment: @thegrinner I just saw the extra line in your answer above! I tried it, and I got this back: kakaw:LTPs111 jenny$ python nameit.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nameit.py", line 22, in <module>
    x = regex.sub(r'\1', namer[name], line)
KeyError: 'AM158981\n'     So does this mean the script is getting messed up from the end-of-line character? Can I escape that somehow (thanks for all the help!)

Comment: @Jen If I remember correctly, you can string the newline by using the string `strip()` method. It will remove whitespace and newline characters from the end of a string. So after you get the name, you do `name = name.strip()`.

Comment: @thegrinner Now I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nameit.py", line 24, in <module>
    x = regex.sub(r'\1', namer[name], line)
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: You know the 'name = name.strip()'? Shouldn't I be striping the \n from the key value, so something like [acs] = acs.strip()? (though when I tried this I got: ValueError: too many values to unpack)

Comment: @Jen I'm not sure where the integer type error is coming from - nothing on that line should require an int. You'll probably want to strip both, yes. It's not necessary though as the key being set in the first loop is going to be just the first word (for example, `AM158981`).

Comment: @thegrinner is it possible that when I strip the \n that the space between the numbers and the accession numbers (so for example: 0 Brucella pinnipedialis Brucellaceae) is also being removed, and so the line becomes an integer since it would become '0BrucellapinnipedialisBrucellaceae' ?

Comment: @Jen It shouldn't. The output of the original split should be a list like `["AM158982", "Brucella ceti Brucellaceae"]`, so the keys should be in the form `"AM158982". The AM on the front should ensure it stays a string. Try printing `name`, `namer[name]`, and `line` before the `regex.sub`.

Comment: @thegrinner when I add `print name` `print namer[name]` and `print line`, I get this (I added commas to separate the three): AM158981,
Brucella pinnipedialis Brucellaceae,

0 AM158981,  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester3.py", line 32, in <module>
    x = regex.sub(r'\1', namer[name], line)
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: @Jen Oh! I think it's the call to `sub()`. I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's supposed to be `re.sub()` - the code you have posted is called on your compiled pattern. See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub). I'm afraid I won't be as helpful with a regex question - you might consider opening a new question that's specific to doing the regex replacement you want.

Comment: @thegrinner Okay, I'll do that, thanks so much for all your help!